# How to cast object property value as an enum

Tags: typescript, enums

I have this enum

```
enum OfferType {
  Apartment = 'apartment',
  House = 'house',
  Room = 'room',
  Hotel = 'hotel',
}
```

Which of the options should be used, when you type the value of the property. When to apply each approach

1)

```
{
  type: type as OfferType
}
```

2. 

```
{
  type: OfferType[type as 'apartment' | 'house' | 'room' | 'hotel']
{
```

Comment: What is the value of `type`? Why is it not *already* an `OfferType`? Are you sure it really has the correct value to be treated as though it were an `OfferType`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that `type` is of type `string` because you're receiving it from something outside the scope of your TypeScript code.

In that case, I wouldn't use either option you've shown, because they both **assume** that `type` is a valid `OfferType`, and that's not a reliable assumption. (But if you want to make that assumption, there's no reason for #2, just use #1; [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBA8gZnYAnAKgTwA7CgbwFBSFQCCGAhkgC4SiVQC8UARGeVTSJUwDQFEASAezABnbIyYALYWJ59CAJUGDoEpMohyiUIZWAAbBs2l79cgL548+4HUqZgALigjKSAJYgA5kZZtqtEwA3FYAxoIgrlCCAEYAVkb42vZYzinYZCKwCMjoWHjmIXjhkYI2AHT6gl4AFLFx5ekM9IzwiKgO5aQUAZwAlEFAA).)

Instead, I'd use either a [type predicate function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) or a [type assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions), which both narrow the type of `type` to `OfferType` **and** check that assumption at runtime.

Type predicate:

```typescript
function isOfferType(value: string): value is OfferType {
    return (Object.values(OfferType) as string[]).includes(value);
}
```

Usage:

```typescript
if (isOfferType(type)) {
    obj = { type };
} else {
    // Handle the fact it isn't one
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBA8gZnYAnAKgTwA7CgbwFBSFQCCGAhkgC4SiVQC8UARGeVTSJUwDQFEASAezABnbIyYALYWJ59CAJUGDoEpMohyiUIZWAAbBs2l79cgL548cMCADGlAJaCQURyPiJUmYAAoAbmT6YMAAXFAilEiOIADmAJThgcHY7rAIyOhYuPJQSMCUYEiuvjAARgBWwA4AdMkhIqUZ3ljxUGQiEVExsQDaALrxNTF2wQAmwI31wPEA3HiWeBOjFNj6BVCUPuGR0XHzjnBQvu6emT6+W61t+Np2LpFQgpVGOJs+UObz5lAGYjnaAD0gJ0ZBAY3Wm0k2DgZAcbjo7hAAHI6C5gDVMQsgA)

Type assertion function:

```typescript
function assertIsOfferType(value: string): asserts value is OfferType {
    if (!(Object.values(OfferType) as string[]).includes(value)) {
        throw new Error(`"${value}" is not a valid OfferType`);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```typescript
assertIsOfferType(type);
const obj = { type };
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBA8gZnYAnAKgTwA7CgbwFBSFQCCGAhkgC4SiVQC8UARGeVTSJUwDQFEASAezABnbIyYALYWJ59CAJUGDoEpMohyiUIZWAAbBs2l79cgL548cMCADGlAJaCQUMiLFUAkiPiJUmMAAFABuZPpgwABcUCKUSI4gAOYAlDHunpQiUGER2I7ZfsjoWLjyUI5wUEEAhEEwAEYAVsAOAHS5kSL1CMWBKW7ZcQnJANoAuiltiXYRACbA3Z3AKQP42tqUkuoA7lAgwHsAokjqSEEABkwAJDjL5kwV2SCCdGQ54Y5zsL0BWBcpADc5UsljwC1mFGw+mAdEogRiw0SSWBGWQlB8RT+wXhWCBeDsLjiUEEzSMOCguOw5kBQA)